# How do you add refs to functional components using withHandlers in Recompose and call ScrollTo on a ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, react-native, recompose

My specific goal is to use the [ScrollTo method](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#methods) of a ScrollView but maintain functional component structure.

More generally this requires getting ref to the current component which [isn't possible with naked react native](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components).

In Dec 2016 **recompose** added [Allows handlers property of withHandlers to be a factory function](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/pull/295) but I can't quite figure out how to use it correctly.

How do you add refs to functional components using withHandlers in Recompose and call ScrollTo on a ScrollView?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
/* ... */

const MyView = ({ onRef, children }) => (
    <View>
        <ScrollView ref={onRef} /* ... */>
            {children}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
)

export default compose(
    withHandlers(() => {
        let myScroll = null;

        return {
            onRef: () => (ref) => (myScroll = ref),
            scrollTo: () => (value) => myScroll.scrollTo(value)
        }
    },
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 100, animated: true })
        }
    })
)(MyView)
```

Comment: this is awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: yup,  brilliant!

Comment: I kept getting scrollTo is not a function. I added `.root` to it and it worked:
`myScroll.root.scrollTo(value)` Not sure why this is the case...

Answer (score 5):

Personally I prefer to initiate Ref as a prop

```
  withProps(() => ({
    ref: React.createRef(),
  })),
```

And then just pass it to your stateless component

```
const MyComponent = ({ ref }) => <Foo ref={ref} />
```

Comment: How would you then use that ref to scroll?

Comment: Just pass the ref to your scroll function.

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't the ref recreated on every rerender this way? Aren't they supposed to be constant?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to make a class as a ref store:

```
const Stateless = ({ refs }) => (
  <div>
    <Foo ref={r => refs.store('myFoo', r)} />
    <div onClick={() => refs.myFoo.doSomeStuff()}>
      doSomeStuff
    </div>
  </div>
)

class RefsStore {
  store(name, value) {
    this[name] = value;
  }
}

const enhancer = compose(
  withProps({ refs: new RefsStore() }),
)(Stateless);
```

Comment: Well, top answer is much more elegant than this monstrosity, but this is the other way you can make things happen.